# WordPress: Is it possible to make one particular post always on TOP on blog.wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a blog on something.wordpress.com , I simply want one post to ALWAYS remain on top. Other posts should go in their regular order. Can someone suggest how to do that OR a theme which makes this possible/?

Comment: Dave. StackOverflow is a community for **programming** questions and answers. Probably you'll find someone with more knowledge about wordpress on superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticky posts are a builtin feature of WordPress. Edit the visibility of a post, and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really a programming question, but it looks like you can get several plugins for Wordpress that will allow you to set a "sticky" post.  Start here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=sticky

Comment: WordPress.com does not allow the use of plugins on their site.